# SQL Как получить значения взависимости от содержимого колонки

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Как получить 10% от зарплаты Боба, 5% от зарплаты Алекса и 30% от зарплаты других сотрудников

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [CASE operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case)

Comment: А как вы сами определили что от зарплаты Боба нужно брать 10%, а от зарплаты Алекса — 5%?

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить еще одну вспомагательную колонку с типом данных "Число с плавающей точкой" где указать % для каждого работника, где по умолчанию буде (0.3) = 30%. А уже при выводе получать суму от процента.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT First_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN First_name = 'Bob' THEN Salary*0.10
        WHEN First_name = 'Alex' THEN Salary*0.5
        WHEN First_name != 'Bob' AND First_name != 'Alex' THEN Salary*0.30
    END as procent
FROM "Employee";
```

Решение оказалось следующим.